# Help with shut down

Tags: 13.04, shutdown

I just built a new computer and installed linux on my old HDD, its working fine excpet when i shut it down from the desktop it wont shut down, i have to manually hold the computers shut down button, until it shut downs.

> Asus Sabertooth z77
>
> i7 3770k
>   GTX 550ti
>
> Corsair 700w (i dont rember anything else about it)
>
> 8gb kingston hyperx blue 1600mhz

aand i dont rember the HDD

when i did sudo shutdown -c and sudo shutdown -h
 now it gave me this :

> . . . .[  242.726776] Power down   [OK]
>
> Unmounting local filesystems   ault/speech-dispatcher [ok]
>
> stopping remaining crypto disks.... 5, shutting down   [Ok]
>
> Stopping early crypto disks         [Fail]
>
> Stopping early crypto disks   [ok]
>
> umount /run/lock: not mounted
>
> umount /run/shm: not mounted
>
> mount: / is busy
>
> Will now halt

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and type `sudo shutdown -P now`?

Comment: Well nothing, the same thing, its stuck on the black screen where reads ubuntu 13.04 and there is something stuff there

Answer (score 0):

Are you taken to the lock screen (login)? Or is it hanging at the ubuntu magenta screen?

 Try running:

```
sudo shutdown -c
sudo shutdown -h now
```

***-c*** cancels scheduled halts and ***-h*** halts the session. These errors happen when an application vetoes the halt; check with gnome-system-monitor for any running scripts or processes that is causing this. Close them and try a normal shutdown from the panel.

Comment: When i did that it gave almost the same things nothing happened